# how does Spring Boot save repositories (JPA relations in both directions)

Tags: jpa, spring-boot

I've 2 classes / entries with `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` linked together (both ways).

Now my thoughts: If I add an element to the collection on one side, is it also on the other one?

so I made this workaround:

```
/**
* use {@link Answer#setExercise(Exercise)} on child
*/
@Deprecated
public void addAnswer(Answer answer) {
    this.answers.add(answer);
}
/**
* use {@link Answer#setExercise(Exercise, boolean)} on child
*/
@Deprecated
public void removeAnswer(Answer answer) {
    this.answers.remove(answer);
}
```

the deprecation is just a warning for myself

```
public void setExercise(Exercise exercise) {
    setExercise(exercise, false);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void setExercise(Exercise exercise, boolean remove) {
this.exercise = exercise;
    if (!remove) {
        exercise.addAnswer(this);
    } else {
        exercise.removeAnswer(this);
    }
}
```

So I want to know if I basically have to do something like this in JPA (with all relations, if I want them in both ways).

Next I want to know how Spring-Boots repositories save objects. Do they save only the element itself or all relations (and back relations)?

*In Spring Boot is it enough to save one object - both relations are stored.*

Comment: If you have any BIDIRECTIONAL relation in JPA then you have to set them at BOTH sides. Always.

Comment: OK, so spring boot doesn't help me here?

Comment: Spring boot does nothing except adding a layer on top of JPA, but all it really does is just JPA stuff.